# Remove object from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following code:

```
app.controller('modalController', function($scope, $http,$modalInstance, $rootScope, items){

   // Get info
   $http.post('/ajax/bundle', {'items':items}).success(function(data){
       $scope.info = data['info'];
   });

   // [BUTTON] Add Bundle
   $scope.selectBundle = function() {

        // Push the info to the cart
        $rootScope.cart.push($scope.info);
        // simplified info
        $rootScope.selectedBundle.push(items)
        // Close modal
        $modalInstance.close();
   }

   // [BUTTON] Remove bundle
   $scope.removeBundle = function() {
        // Run all bundles
        angular.forEach($rootScope.selectedBundle,function(value, key){
           // Exists
           if (angular.equals(value,items)) {
               // Remove simplified
               $rootScope.selectedBundle.splice($rootScope.selectedBundle.indexOf(value), 1);
               // remove form cart
               // $rootScope.cart.splice($rootScope.cart.indexOf($scope.info), 1);
           }
       });

       // Close modal
       $modalInstance.close();
   }
});
```

When i use:

```
console.log($rootScope.cart);
console.log($scope.dados);
console.log($rootScope.cart.indexOf($scope.dados));
```

in $scope.selectBundle, returns correct position

Now, when i use in $scope.removeBundle, always returns -1 (not found)

Someone can help me?

Comment: what is the value of items in if(angular.equals(value,items)) ?

Comment: items = [bundle, thickness, grade, cod, nbloco];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not it just an array? Why not just empty it ?

```
// [BUTTON] Remove bundle
$scope.removeBundle = function() {
     $rootScope.selectedBundle = [];
     $modalInstance.close();
}
```

Take 2: You don't need to search for index of `value` - it is supplied by `angular.forEach`. When iterating through object your get `key`, but for arrays your get `index`

```
$scope.removeBundle = function() {
    angular.forEach($rootScope.selectedBundle,function(value, index){
        $rootScope.selectedBundle.splice(index, 1);
    });

   $modalInstance.close();
```

}

Comment: because I can't let it blank , I want to remove only one array

Comment: From the code you provided it's difficult to understand what exactly you want to delete. and the console.log examples don't add any clarity. They are only confusing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your equality function is incorrect? Could you create a jsFiddle or Plunker? In the meantime.. try passing the thing you want removed into the calling function, like such:

```
// [BUTTON] Remove bundle
$scope.removeBundle = function(someItemToRemove) {
    console.log(someItemToRemove); // pass item to remove
    angular.forEach($rootScope.selectedBundle, function(value, key){
       // Exists
       if (value === someItemToRemove) {
           $rootScope.selectedBundle.splice($rootScope.selectedBundle.indexOf(value), 1);
       }
    });

    // Close modal
    $modalInstance.close();
}
```

Comment: When i remove bundle 757... my selected bundles removes correctly, but cart don't remove correctly